# Material-UI: Uncaught TypeError when swapping between two Drawer components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Note: I'm using `material-ui 3.3.0`

I'm looking to create two `<Drawer>` components on a page. The first appears from the left, the other from the right. Two `<Button>` components sit in an `<AppBar>` and are used to toggle each drawer respectively.

This all works fine, however when `rightDrawer` is open and the button for `leftDrawer` is clicked (setting `leftOpen:true` and `rightOpen:false`), I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
  at ariaHidden (manageAriaHidden.js:28)
  at ModalManager.remove (ModalManager.js:188)
  at Modal._this.handleClose (Modal.js:145)
  at Modal.componentDidUpdate (Modal.js:221)
  at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:14369)
  at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:15462)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
  at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
  at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
  at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:15603)
  at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:16618)
  at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16563)
  at performWork (react-dom.development.js:16482)
  at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:16454)
  at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:16719)
  at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2150)
  at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4532)
```

What's unusual is that this doesn't seem to be the case the other way around.

Here's a basic code snippet demonstrating my problem:

```
class Test extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      leftOpen: false,
      rightOpen: false
    }

    this.toggleLeftPanel = () => {
      this.setState({
        leftOpen: !this.state.leftOpen, 
        rightOpen: false
      });
    }

    this.toggleRightPanel = () => {
      this.setState({
        rightOpen: !this.state.rightOpen,
        leftOpen: false
      });
    }
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.AppBar}
        {this.getDrawer(this.state.leftOpen, 'left')}
        {this.getDrawer(this.state.rightOpen, 'right')}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

  get AppBar()
  {
    return (
      <AppBar position='relative' color='primary' style={{height: 64, zIndex: 9999}}>
        <Toolbar>
          {this.getButton(this.state.leftOpen ? 'flat' : 'raised', this.toggleLeftPanel)}
          <div style={{flexGrow: 1}}/>
          {this.getButton(this.state.rightOpen ? 'flat' : 'raised', this.toggleRightPanel)}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }

  getButton(variant, onClick)
  {
    return (
      <Button variant={variant} onClick={onClick}>
        {"open"}
      </Button>
    )
  }

  getDrawer(isOpen, anchor)
  {
    return (
      <Drawer open={isOpen} anchor={anchor}>
        <div style={{width: 100}}/>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried setting a delay (via `setTimeout`) between when the 'toggle' turns on one panel, and turns off the other to see if that bypasses the issue.. but to no avail.

Comment: What version of material-ui are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a current issue on version 3.3.0, solution seems to be to roll back to @material-ui/core@3.2.2 and version locking the package.json

```
npm install @material-ui/core@3.2.2
```

EDIT: seems to be fixed in 3.3.2 upgrade and you should be fine!